# Import matrix from .txt file with format

Tags: python, matrix

Very new to python. Let say I have a txt file which contains a matrix.

`matrix.txt`

```
A A A B B C
D D C D A E
A D S A W A
```

Now I want to import this matrix to my python program so that I can deal with the data.
Now the question is how should I do to append each line of matrix?

What I tried:

```
file_object = open('matrix.txt', 'r')
try:
   line = file_object.readline()
   while line:
       print line
       line = file_object.readline()
       line = line.strip()
       string = []
       string.append(line)
       print string
finally:
   file_object.close()
print string[0][1]
```

**Edit:** Special situation:

```
A A A B B C           A A A B B C
  D C D A E   --->    0 D C D A E
  D   A W A           0 D 0 A W A
```

So if some elements are nil, how could I replace them with `0`?

Comment: You're not making any any sense in your question. Append lines to Python? You don't append anything to a language.

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo. :)

Comment: Just so you know, file objects are iterable meaning you can use a for loop to retrieve every line within a file rather than this obscure while loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit exhaustive code with explanations:

```
#define a separator which divides your elements
sep = ' '
matrix = []
with open('matrix.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        # generate an array with the elements which are on the line
        line_array = line.split(sep)

        #append it to the matrix
        matrix.append(line_array)

print matrix
```

In order to better understand the 'with' statement, read [this](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm), it helped me.

Edit:
In order to match double-separators as a nil (None) object, replace the line_array association with:

```
line_array = [e or 0 for e in line.split(sep)]
```

Example dataset (notice double space between B and C):

```
A A A B  C
D D C D A E
A D S A W A
```

Edit 2:
For platform independent line endings, use:

```
line_array = [e or 0 for e in line.splitlines()[0].split(sep)]
```

Comment: If some elements of the matrix is nil, how can I replace the element with 0?

Comment: What do you mean by "is nill"? How would this be represented in your dataset? For the case of two items separated by two instead of one separator, see response.

Comment: Eh，why I got something strange? something like been encoded.

Comment: It might be because of line endings which are different on *nix / Windows, I am using the former. Do you get some \n type of characters in your matrix?

Comment: Updated with platform independent line splitting.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('matrix.txt') as data:
    matrix = [i.split() for i in data]
```

Comment: Thanks Malik. If some elements of the matrix is `nil`, how can I replace the element with `0`?

Comment: Easy let me change it up.

Comment: See my edit. Unfortunately, this doesn't work. The  `matrix[2][0]` should be `0`, but in your case, it is `D`.

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant a literal string, let me fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
matrix = []
for lines in open('matrix.txt', 'r'):
    matrix.append(lines.split())
```

Comment: If some elements of the matrix is nil, how can I replace the element with 0?

Comment: @Wongzigii Could you provide input file for such situation?